# Regex replace using pattern

Tags: regex

I need to replace a pattern matched by regex with another pattern using regex, in C++.

Example -
We have the following characters: "a" and "b"

I want to replace like this -

Original text -

```
aabaaaaaaabaaabab
```

Replacement -

```
abbabbbbbbbabbbab
```

I found the following regex for getting the matches -

```
aa+b
```

What regex replace pattern must be applied to get the desired replacement?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Please explain the replacement logic clearly.  2) Also tell us what language or tool you are using here.

Comment: In C++, 
"aab" must be replaced by "abb", 
"aaab" must be replaced by "abbb",
"aaaab" must be replaced by "abbbb",
and so on...

Comment: @RyanLarson Can you please UnDelete [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71181810/c-fast-iterate-and-modify-operations) that you have deleted today? There is an UnDelete button (link) under question's body. Because I just implemented very fast solution for it, quite large and complex code with C++ classes, spent several hours of coding. I want to post an answer to your question with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using lookarounds be a possibility for you, here is one solution.  Match on the following pattern:

```regex
(?<=a)a(?=a*b)
```

and then replace with just a single `b`.  The pattern says to match:

```regex
(?<=a)   assert that at least one 'a' precedes (i.e. ignore first 'a')
a        a letter 'a'
(?=a*b)  which is following by zero or more 'a' then a 'b'
```

Here is working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wCj8vq/1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is not limited to the letters `'a'` and `'b'`.

Matches of the following regular expression are to be replaced by the content of capture group 2.

```
(?<=(.))\1(?=\1*(.))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CgkwHn/1)

The regular expression is comprised of the following elements.

```
(?<=    # begin a positive lookbehind
  (.)   # match any character and save to capture group 1
)       # end positive lookbehind  
\1      # match the content of capture group 1 
(?=     # begin a positive lookahead
  \1*   # match the content of capture group 1 zero or more times
  (.)   # match any character and save to capture group 2
)       # end positive lookahead
```